# ruby: name of this syntax, which splits positional argument of block

Tags: ruby, syntax

I see a piece of code today

```
#! cruby 1.9
lam = lambda do |(a,b),c|
#blahblah
end
```

It seemingly equals to

```
lam = lambda do |l,c|
a,b = *l
#blahblah
end
```

Are there 'official name' for this syntax?

Comment: Thanks for asking, learned something new!

Comment: Don't reuse `l` as a local var name please, you confused the hell out of me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is called [destructuring](http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html).

> So what is destructuring? The most concise definition I found is from [Common Lisp the Language](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node252.html). *Destructuring allows you to bind a set of variables to a corresponding set of values anywhere that you can normally bind a value to a single variable.* It is a powerful feature of Clojure that lets you write some very elegant code. For more information about Clojure's features, I recommend you check out Jay Field's [blog post](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html) on the subject. While destructuring in Ruby is not quite as powerful as Clojure, you can still do some cool stuff.